# Installing only production files using bower

Tags: jquery, npm, bower

When I something via bower, rather then only the needed production files, annoyingly, a whole bunch of extra files appear into my working directory.

For example, installing jQuery:

```
bower install jquery
```

two folders are installed inside the jQuery directory, `dist` and `src`. `dist` is fine. But `src` contain a lots of unnecessary files, *(jquery's core which jquery was built on top.)*

[image: contents of src folder]

In this scenario, is there any way to install jQuery without the `src` directory? Only the `dist`?

Comment: Quite possibly the `--production` option...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -P install option which will stop bower from installing dev dependancies but this all depends on the package you're trying to install being configured right for production dependancies and dev dependancies.

See http://bower.io/docs/api/#install for more information on bower install flags.